# Choose which component to show on certain route in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Is it possible to set a condition in a route to decide which component to show in it? Something like this:

```
let someBoolean = true;

const routes = [
  { path: '/foo', component: someBoolean ? Foo : Baz },
  { path: '/bar', component: Bar }
]
```

And boolean value can be changed. Depending on that component should also be chosen.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-routing-example-forked-oeb4g), it is possible.

However, the routes tree is built at the app startup, so if you change the variable through an action from your app, nothing should happen, the tree shouldn't be built again.

EDIT:

Vue Router has an API that allows you to update your tree after the tree was built.

You have [Router.addRoute()](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-addroute), and [this trick](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1234#issuecomment-357941465) that allows you to reset the tree to its initial state and conditionally add the route you want to keep.

Comment: I've tried that way, but I don't think it'll work with changable boolean value.

Comment: This is what I meant by `the tree shouldn't be build again`. If you wish to update your tree, see the edits I added to my answer.